# Não consigo usar o SceneBuilder com o Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

Olá, eu tenho o Eclipse (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers) e queria instalar o JavaFX.
Já instalei o e(fx)clipse e reiniciei a IDE.
Mas quando vou criar um novo projeto em New > Other, a pasta JavaFX não aparece pra mim.
Já tentei ir em Window > Preferences e lá não aparece o campo para colocar o caminho do arquivo executável do SceneBuilder.
Já vi diversos tutoriais mas nada me ajudou. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que eu posso fazer?

[image: Plug-in do e(fx)clipse]
[image: A pasta do JavaFX não aparece no Wizard na hora de criar um projeto]
[image: Não aparece o campo para colar o caminho do executável do SceneBuilder]

Answer (score 1):

Ola, ocorreu o mesmo problema comigo! a unica forma que achei foi instalando o JavaFX direto do Merketplace do eclipse, desta forma ira funcionar.

> Help>Eclipse Merketplace> "Pesquise por JavaFX".